# Filtering the rows in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I currently have the JQuery plugin DataTables working correctly and I have inserted a button at the top of the page to filter the list further. (I have also used the search bar built into DataTables). I want the button to filter the table down and only show rows that contain a certain value.. Below is what ive been doing, but nothing seems to work.. In the example below I am trying to filter the list to all rows that contain the element 'Dog' within the 'Animal' column Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

```
$("#NewButton").click(function() {  
     $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
      table.draw();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).attr(Animal) == "Dog";
        }
    );  
    table.draw();
    });

    $("#Default").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    table.draw();
    });
```

Comment: Check this out - this is how I do it: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: See if my solution is what you're looking for - let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I really appreciate it! I am more looking for pre-filtering within the code so when the button is pressed it filters the table automatically without having to type in the search boxes..

Comment: Yeah, I was giving you an example of how it works - adapting it should be fairly straightforward. You just tap into the `column().search()` API exactly how I do in my function below. And instead of my change/input handlers, adapt those to button click handlers or however you'd like to do it

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from my code -- it's with using `<input>` and `<select>`, but you should be able to adapt it very easily if you are trying to do something differently.

In the example provided on `datatables.net`, they do it with the search fields in the footer (which I personally dislike), so my example is with them in the header. For starters, you will need **two** rows in your `<thead>` -- **make sure your filter row is the first row, and your actual headers is the second row**

**[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/boqevupowe/edit?output)**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="filter-row">
      <th class="actions">
      </th>
      <th class="searchable datatables-dropdown">
        <select name="FormName">
          <option>Form1</option>
          <option>Form2</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th class="display-order">
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Label Text
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        View Roles
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Edit Roles
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Delete Roles
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Add Roles
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Field Type
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Note Field
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Note Required
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Default
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Reason List Group
      </th>
      <th class="searchable">
        Reason Required
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="actions">
        Actions
      </th>
      <th>
        Form Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Display Order
      </th>
      <th>
        Label Text
      </th>
      <th>
        View Roles
      </th>
      <th>
        Edit Roles
      </th>
      <th>
        Delete Roles
      </th>
      <th>
        Add Roles
      </th>
      <th>
        Field Type
      </th>
      <th>
        Note Field
      </th>
      <th>
        Note Required
      </th>
      <th>
        Note Default
      </th>
      <th>
        Reason List Group
      </th>
      <th>
        Reason Required
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>

  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, in your JavaScript, you can convert your filter rows from the plain text to the `<input>` elements like so:

```
$(function () {
    // First -- Convert plain text to search field inputs
    $('.table thead tr:first th.searchable:not(.datatables-dropdown)').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text().trim();
        $(this).css({ "padding": "5px" });
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" style="width: 115px;" />');
    });

    // Then -- initialize DataTable
    var table = $(".table").DataTable({
        // ... Initialization options
    });

    // Lastly -- call function for wiring up the search fields to the table passed in
    ApplySearchFieldsToDatatable(table);
});

function ApplySearchFieldsToDatatable (table) {
    // https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
    table.columns().every(function () {
        var column = this,
        header = $(column.header()), // returns LAST <tr> in <thead>

        // we need to also grab the first <tr> in <thead> because that is where the search boxes are
        searchHeader = header.parent().prev(),

        // Get the corrisponding <th> in the first <tr> (the filter row) 
        currentColumn = searchHeader.children(":eq(" + header.index() + ")");

        // Unbind existing event listeners on old column position
        $('select', currentColumn).off("change");
        $('input', currentColumn).off("input").off("propertychange");

        // Add new event listeners for new column position
        $('select', currentColumn).on('change', function () {
            if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                column.search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });
        $('input', currentColumn).on('input propertychange', function () {
            if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                column.search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });

        // Need to set the value of the inputs/selects to the search value saved by "stateSave: true"
        // This is needed on page reload when the search state gets saved, but the inputs get redrawn 
        // from scratch. They do not inherently retain their value, so the data in the table does not
        // match the values in the search fields.
        if (column.search().length) {
            currentColumn.find('input').val(column.search());
            currentColumn.find('select').val(column.search());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I currently have this working..
 $("#button1").click(function() { 
         table.column( 2 ).search( 'Dog' ).draw();
         });

I was just wondering whether fnMultiFilter would work better as I currently cannot work out how to filter based on the input in two columns????

Comment: @user2964762 `table.column(2).search("Dog"); table.column(3).search("Cat"); table.draw();` should work for filtering on multiple columns - that's exactly what this code does, it just does it generically, rather than hard-coding the columns and search values