# Search Table using Data Tables numeric search

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable, web-frontend

I was wondering if it is possible to filter by first element data-table ?
Example if i have database of :

```
11220
15863
15687
45454 
51421
54821  
89854
```

search by: 5
I want to look from the first element 
so it means output:

```
51421
54821
```

search by : 51 
output: 51421

```
  var table = $('#min-table').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip',
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sDom": "lrtip",
    "lengthMenu": [[20, 35, 50, -1], [20, 35, 50, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 20.

});

    $('input[type = search]').on('keyup', function () {


        table.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
        .draw();
    });
```

Comment: Isn't it the default behavior ? What's happening ?

Comment: This should be working by default. At least it works for me.

Comment: datatables have a built in search that should filter already, what have you tried?  what does your code look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering the rows in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832748/filtering-the-rows-in-datatables)

Comment: it shows all numbers that contain 5 digit ..
for example it shows me also 15687
                                                15863
                                                 51421
                                                  54821

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) here:

```
column
    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
    .draw();
```

My suggestion: Use regex, to ensure that the value entered is at the start of the string, and doesn't contain the string.

Comment: I didnt manage to make it work ! .. I put some code how it looks but still not working

Comment: Don't use `$`, as that matches the end of the string.

Comment: it still shows all numbers that contain digit 5 .. for example it shows me also 15687 15863 51421 54821 ... but i want to filer only the one that start with 5